# Loop echo something every 4th time in php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop, modulo

I want to do something in a loop every fourth time for 2 times.. so for example if I want to echo four times "hello" and after that two times "good bye"it would look like that

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
goodbye
goodbye
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

....
and so on..

i have tried something like that..

```
if ($x==4) {echo 'hello'; }
else {echo 'goodybe'; }
```

how can i do somethling like that in php?

Can i use modulo for that?

I am just not getting it... thank you!

Comment: isn't that what you learn in your "introduction to programming" classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a modulo.  It's good for nth time with simple arithmetic.  When you were a child in grade school, you did modulo math:  it's the remainder in the quotient of a division problem.  When the remainder is zero, then you have evenly divided.

Zero modulo an integer will yield zero.  So, the outer iteration loop below begins at one so that you can skip over a common base case of $x=0.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <11; $x++){
    // inside a given loop of ten iterations . . . 

    // determine if this is a plain case or the 4th time
    // if it is the fourth time, load a 1 in $type; otherwise, load a 0.
    $type = ((($x%4)==0)?1:0);
    // prepare to respond with hello or goodbye based on $type
    $output = (($type==0)?"hello":"goodbye");
    // echo $output once or twice based on $type
    for($i=0, $j=1+$type; $i < $j ;$i++){
        echo "<p>$x $output</p>";

    }
}
```

Will generate output like:

1 hello

2 hello

3 hello

4 goodbye

4 goodbye

5 hello

6 hello

7 hello

8 goodbye

8 goodbye

9 hello

10 hello

Answer (score 2):

For example something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    for ($n = 0; $n < 4; $n++) {
        print "hello";
    }
    for ($m = 0; $m < 2; $m++) {
        print "goodbye";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (($x % 6) < 4) {
  echo 'hello';
}
else {
  echo 'goodbye'; 
}
```